# Proof about determinant for a special matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given a $n\times n$ matrix 
     $$A=
 \begin{pmatrix}
 a_{1}+p&p&p&p&\cdots & p&p&p\\
 p&a_{2}+p&p&p&\cdots&p&p&p\\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\\
 p&p&p&p&\cdots&p&a_{n-1}+p&p\\
 p&p&p&p&\cdots&p&p&a_{n}+p
 \end{pmatrix}
 $$

we have
$$\det A =
\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{i}\right)\left(1+p\sum_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{a_i}\right)$$

My attempt was to prove that by induction which turned out to be tedious.

Comment: To reduce it to the second factor, multiply the $j$th row by $a_ja_j^{-1}$ and then "pull out" each $a_j$ in front of the determinant.

Comment: You could use that $\det$ is linear in each column. Then, it is a simple induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the bottom row from the others to get $$\mathrm{det} \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & 0 & ... & -a_n \\ 0 & a_2 & ... & -a_n \\ ... & ... & ... & ... \\ p & p & ... & a_n + p \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then column expansion along the first column: $$a_1 \cdot \mathrm{det} \begin{pmatrix} a_2 & 0 & ... & -a_n \\ 0 & a_3 & ... & -a_n \\ ... & ... & ... & ... \\ p & p & ... & a_n + p \end{pmatrix} + (-1)^{n-1} p \cdot \mathrm{det} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & ... & -a_n \\ a_2 & 0 & ... & -a_n \\ ... & ... & ... & ... \\ 0 & 0 & ... & -a_n \end{pmatrix}.$$ The first determinant is known by induction from the case $n-1$. The second is upper-triangular after permuting the rows.